# Having trouble with while loops

Tags: c++, c

I do not understand why nothing is showing up on the screen when I run this little program? Is the while loop even starting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char word[20]; 
  char TryAgain[20] = "y";
  int WordLength = 0;

  while (strcmp(TryAgain, "y"))
  {
    printf("\t\t\t Word \n\n");
    printf("What is your word, bird?\n");
    scanf("%s", word);
    getchar();

    WordLength = strlen(word); 

    printf("Result: "); 
    for (int i = 0; i < WordLength; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c*", word[i]);
    }
    printf("\nWould you like to try another word? [y/n]\n");
    scanf("%s", TryAgain);
  }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, but be prepared for a lot of critique if you tag a question both **c++** and **c**.  You really have to establish which language you are using, because they aren't 100% compatible...but moreover, the way of thinking about problems is quite different, with C++ being much more abstract and high-level.  *(For instance, in C++ your mistake here wouldn't happen because you'd be using a string class that would allow you to use the equality operator a la `while (TryAgain == "y")`, just for instance.)*

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, you should switch to using `std::string` for text strings instead of the problematic C-style (null terminated character sequence) string.

Answer (score 5):

`strcmp` returns 0 if its arguments are the same, so at the first iteration your while loop is checking `while(0)`. 0 is equivalent to `false` in boolean checks so the while loop is skipped. Try `while(!strcmp(TryAgain, "y"))`.

Comment: @user2836816 There is an accept button to check a solution when it solves your problem...which is the general way of thanking people.

Comment: @Rizier123 Ah, the 15 minutes.  Forgot about that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to change it to a do-while

```
do {
  printf("\nWould you like to try another word? [y/n]\n");
  scanf("%s", TryAgain);
} while (TryAgain=="y" || TryAgain=="Y");
```

the TryAgain must be boolean.
see ya

Comment: Except for the fact that it doesn't work!  You can't use `==` for testing equality of C strings, as it just tests if the pointers are equal.